# RS485 Functionality difference

Tags: power-electronics, modbus

I would like to major difference between these ICS.

1. [Max 485 Low power Slew rate limited](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1487-MAX491.pdf)
2. [SN75176 :Differential Bus Transceiver](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn75176a.pdf)
3. [ADM 2483  Differential Bus Transceiver](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADM2483.pdf)

ADM 2483 is Isolated type power supply. I could not able to differentiate  functionality

I read in forums all are same but difference in functionality. I could not able to find difference .

Comment: What do the data sheets tell you about the major differences and what would you regard as "major"?

Comment: Look for the money

Comment: It would be a better design question to say . these are ALL my requirements, which would be best suited?  The ADM2483 is slew-limited to reduce reflections with
improperly terminated transmission lines. The controlled slew
rate limits the data rate to 500 kbps. The device’s input impedance
is 96 kΩ, allowing up to 256 transceivers on the bus..

Answer (score 2):

> all are same but difference in functionality

Huh? what does it even mean? They all are RS-485 transceivers, so their functionality is exactly the same, except ADM2483 provides additional isolation function.

MAX485 is **not** slew limited. It is pretty regular one unit load (up to 32 receivers) 2.5Mbps transceiver.

SN75176A is also one unit load but faster 5Mbps transceiver. SN75176B is even faster at 10Mbps.

ADM2483 **is** slew-limited and isolated 1/8 load transceiver. Up to 256 receivers at 500 kbps.